# Using regex in a variable

Tags: java, regex, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse a file listed with applicable regex, accepting the regex string to a variable and then use it in a expression. But while in doing so I'm facing troubles with \ and could not use them. Below is the block which is using the code. Can you tell me why it is working for ""©?.*"" and not for ""©?\\s*\\w+.*"". The expression is valid otherwise.

```
String valuePattern = attrs.getNamedItem("valuePattern").getTextContent();
if (newNodeName == "") {
    System.out.println(valuePattern);
    // System.out.println("Inside Delete node...");
    if (valuePattern == ""
        || (valuePattern != "" && node.getTextContent().matches(valuePattern))) {
        System.out.println("in match");
        System.out.println("Deleting: " + node.getTextContent());
        node = null;
    }
```

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. Note that comparing strings with `==` and `!=` almost certainly doesn't do what you think it does... (And it's not at all clear that your question has anything *really* to do with XML. If it's a matter of finding out why a regular expression does or doesn't match some text, it doesn't matter where the text comes from.)

Comment: Please provide an [MVCE (minimal complete verifiable example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What is `node.getTextContent()`?

Answer (score 0):

As Jon Skeet pointed out, first of all, you should repair your String comparison.

```
String valuePattern = attrs.getNamedItem("valuePattern").getTextContent();
if (("").equals(newNodeName) {
    System.out.println(valuePattern);
    if (("").equals(valuePattern)
        || (!("").equals(valuePattern) && node.getTextContent().matches(valuePattern))) {
        System.out.println("in match");
        System.out.println("Deleting: " + node.getTextContent());
        node = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no problem if you compare null with the earlier syntax. Hence that is not a problem.